# Find logs between timestamps using stackdriver CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver

I need to find logs between two timestamps using stackdriver CLI. I used the below command.

```
gcloud beta logging read "timestamp>=\"2017-02-19T00:00:00Z\" AND timestamp<\"2017-03-14T00:00:00Z\""
```

But its giving me the error:

**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Here is my gcloud version details

[image: gcloud --version]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a product manager with Stackdriver logging.  We've tested the command and it seemed to work fine.  The issue may be with Windows command shell?  One guess is that perhaps the ">" and "<" need "/" in front?  Copying and pasting your query into cloud shell works fine.

Kudos go to a Google engineer who recommended this:
I came across this issue a lot with gcloud --filter commands on windows. The following works:

```
gcloud beta logging read "timestamp^>=""2017-02-19T00:00:00Z"" AND ""timestamp^<2017-03-14T00:00:00Z"""
```

Note use of double "" and ^ escape characters.

You can add --verbosity debug to the command line, it will show you how exactly parameters were understood by gcloud.

Comment: As you mentioned the command is working fine from gcloud shell in the browser, but is failing in Windows command shell.

Comment: After adding ^ before < and adding the extra " the command is working fine. Thank you Team. Here is the command I used. **gcloud beta logging read "logName=projects/myproject/logs/output_log AND Exception AND timestamp^>=""2017-03-22T14:01:32Z"" AND timestamp^<""2017-03-22T15:50:04Z""" --format=table(resource.labels.zone,labels.'compute.googleapis.com/resource_name',timestamp,textPayload)**

Comment: Does this still work? 
❯ gcloud logging read 'timestamp^>="2019-08-08T21:00:00Z"'
ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field not found: 'timestamp^'.

Answer (score 7):

The above answer doesn't seem to work anymore. Here's the new command.

```
gcloud logging read 'receiveTimestamp>="2019-08-08T21:00:00Z" AND receiveTimestamp<="2019-08-08T22:00:00Z"'
```

Actually, this is simpler. The escape characters has been removed along with the double "double quotes". :)

Answer (score 5):

you can simply use the following command to get logs based on timestamps and other filter conditions-

```
gcloud logging read 
"resource.type=cloud_run_revision
 resource.labels.service_name=new_service
 timestamp>=\"2021-08-30T00:00:01.086988Z\" AND timestamp<=\"2021-08-30T23:59:59.086988Z\""
 --format json > logs.json
```

This is tested and verified on **03 Sept 2021**

Comment: Worked for me, once I added timestamp inside the same quote after read

`gcloud logging read "resource.type="k8s_pod" timestamp>=\"2022-06-14T11:13:54.052235Z\ and timestamp<=\"2022-06-14T15:00:00Z\"""`