# SDK Gcloud logging timestamp filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am having problem while trying to filter my log files to a specific period of time. Everything beside timestamps works fine when i'm trying to write a command. The moment everything looks good:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=XXX logName=projects/YYY/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.health_check" > test.txt
```

All other things like --limit or --freshness are working without problems, but when i'm trying to get a period of time in my text file the command stops working. I'm getting information:

> The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I've tried many things and this is command which gives me some error at least:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=XXX logName=projects/YYY/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.health_check timestamp='2020-01-22T14:02:41.41Z'"
```

Please help me with correct syntax of specifying timestamps to get any period of time as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=XXX logName=projects/YYY/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.health_check timestamp^>=""2020-01-21T11:00:00Z"" timestamp^<=""2020-01-22T11:00:00Z""" >t.txt
```

I found it here: [Find logs between timestamps using stackdriver CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817841/find-logs-between-timestamps-using-stackdriver-cli?rq=1)

Thank you Braulio Baron for your help!

Comment: nice! please upvote your own answer. :) glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is in the timestamp, it should be with `\` before the date's quotes:

`gcloud logging read "resource.type=gae_app AND logName=projects/xxxx/logs/syslog AND timestamp=\"2020-01-22T14:02:41.41Z\""`

For more detail have a look into [gcloud logging read](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read)

Comment: Your command's working but whenever i'm putting "<"  or ">"symbol to it, it stops working. As i mentioned i need a period of time for example between 21.01 and 22.01. I made this command with your hints but still got some problems:

gcloud logging read "resource.type=XXX AND logName=projects/YYY/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.health_check"
AND timestamp>=\"2020-01-21T12:00:00Z\" timestamp<=\"2020-01-22T12:00:00Z\"

Comment: Try adding `AND` in the last part, it should be like this: `gcloud logging read "resource.type=XXX AND logName=projects/YYY/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.health_check AND timestamp>=\"2020-01-21T12:00:00Z\" AND timestamp<=\"2020-01-22T12:00:00Z\" "`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. 
Whenever i'm using "<" i'm getting: "The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."
Maybe i can do what i want by making command to give back logs before some date and limit it with "--limit" but even this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found command which passes, but gives me no logs in command window or in text file it's making:
`gcloud beta logging read "timestamp^>=""2020-01-21T11:00:00Z"" AND ""timestamp^<2020-01-22T11:00:00Z"""`